# Regex for fixing 'and' and 'or' in solr queries with c#

Tags: c#, regex, solr

We need to handle AND and OR entered by users, via a c# dot net web app, to solr "q=" queries.  It also has to handle quoted phrases (this is the hard part...) properly.

Da Rules:
'Or' has to be removed, unless it is in a quoted string.
'And' has to be all uppercase, unless it is in a quoted string.

The problem, of course, is that a regex that matches OR also matches "OR", we need one that matches OR but *not* "OR".

Given input of:
A OR B, c "OR" d,"e OR f"

The output must be:
A B, c "OR" d,"e OR f"

Given input of:
A and B, c "and" d,"e and f"

The output must be:
A AND B, c "and" d,"e and f"

Comment: Do you allow escape characters, or is a " always the beginning or end of a quoted string?

Comment: The quoted string always begins and ends with ". EX:
'This and that or "a and b"

returns

'This AND that "a and b"

Comment: Any other lucene query modifiers go through un-modified.

Comment: regex is not the solution to every text-manipulation problem.  What about quoted quotes?

Comment: Have you considered using the .Net client for Solr? SolrNet -  http://code.google.com/p/solrnet

Comment: I've been trying to get solr.net in here for a couple of months.  $BigGovernmentAgency is a bit paranoid.  Especially about open sores software.

Comment: @ben  

At some point we have to be able to tell the users "Don't do that!" otherwise we might as well write our own search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Match both OR and "OR" (or AND and "AND")(say that 5 times fast), and use a custom replace delegate to determine if we are replacing and, is so, what.

```
public string Fixup(string input)
{
//matches any quoted string containing the words OR or AND: "a and b" matches, 
//"andor" does not. 
string pattern1=@"""\w*?\W*?\b(AND|OR)\W*?\w*?"""; 
string pattern2=@"\b(AND|OR)\b"; //matches AND or OR as standalone words
string pattern3=pattern1+"|"+pattern2;//matches either pattern

MatchEvaluator Eval=ReplaceMatch;//set the delegate

string output=Regex.Replace(input,pattern3,Eval,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

return output;
}

public string ReplaceMatch(Match m)
{
string str=m.Value;
if(str.Contains("\""))return str;//do nothing if it's a quoted string
if(str.ToLower().Contains("or")) return String.Empty;//strip out 'or' from the query
return str.ToUpper();// string is 'and', uppercase it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming " can't be escaped within a quoted string, you could also use groups in your MatchEvaluator, like so:

```
// Check for "[^"]*" first to filter out any quoted strings
// Assign any matches of AND to the "AND" group
// Assign any matches of OR to the "OR" group
const string pattern = @"(""[^""]*"")|\s+((?<AND>AND)|(?<OR>OR))\s+";

public static string FixUp(string s)
{
    return Regex.Replace(s, pattern, ReplaceANDsAndORs, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

public static string ReplaceANDsAndORs(Match m)
{
    if (m.Groups["AND"].Length > 0)
    {
        return " AND ";
    }
    else if (m.Groups["OR"].Length > 0)
    {
        return " ";
    }
    else
    {
        return m.Value;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: The processing for "AND" matches was removing the whitespace around them (i.e. "a and b" was being updated to "aANDb").  This has been corrected.